# Helper Function In Laravel

Tags: composer-php

Hello Guys  I tried  To Made A Helper Function Like asset Using Laravel 9.21.6

**This Is My Code**

**Helper.php**

```
<?php

function show_name() {
    return 'Ahmed Emmam';
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('test-helper' , function () {
    show_name();
});
```

**composer.json**

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "files" : [
    "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
],
```

The Error Is `Call to undefined function show_name()`

i ran `Composer dump-autoload`  but it's failed

Can Anyone Help Me Please

Comment: Make sure your folder and php file's name are correct. Because composer is case sensitive. There may be some issues about Upper or Lowercase letters.

Comment: No Of These Answers are worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the other files within the `autoload` field.

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { ... },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

Comment: it dosent't Work

Comment: @BexelX This is how I load my files in every project, so it works. You've written `files` outside the `autoload` field and it's wrong. If you still have the same problem, check the file path and make sure that the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use`function_exists` function

```
if (!function_exists('show_name')) {
    function show_name()
    {
        return 'Ahmed Emmam';
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. It just avoid duplications if some function named `show_name` has been defined somewhere else.

Comment: it dosent't Work